# Use of unassigned local variable in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my script to control the movement of my shots.. 
But i get the error:

> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `floorHit'

How can I fix it?

```
void Start(){
    floor = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
    Ray RAY = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit floorHit;
    Vector3 playerMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
    playerMouse.y = 0f;
    MoveTo (playerMouse.x, playerMouse.z);
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize floorHit before using it

Comment: There are tons of topics online about that. Please next time do some research..

Comment: To be fair to him the way this works in unity is it's value is set as an output parameter of another method.

Comment: Please use the proper tag for Unity3D.  The `Unity` tag is not for the Unity game engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of ray needs to be set by adding the line

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out floorHit)) {
    //add logic here for what to do if we hit
    }
```

Just after declaring it.

So the full example is

```
void Start(){
    floor = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit floorHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out floorHit)) {
        Vector3 playerMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
        playerMouse.y = 0f;
        MoveTo (playerMouse.x, playerMouse.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `ray` should be `RAY` and `hit` should be `floorHit`.

Comment: Did you mean `Physics.Raycast (ray, out floorHit)) ` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a new instance of your `RaycastHit`-class:

```
RaycastHit floorHit = new RaycastHit();
Vector3 playerMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
```

Comment: His floorHit object would be initialised, but never set to the value he is after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate `floorhit`:

```c#
RaycastHit floorHit = new RaycastHit();
```